# Event handler for left-click on Notebook tabs in Tkinter

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, mouseevent

In Tkinter, I want to make it so when I click one or more times on an already open/selected tab of a Notebook object so that it does not take the focus (or so that it gives the focus back to the Text widget in the window).

How do I do this?

If there's an event handler for clicking on tabs, that would more than suffice.

Also, if there's an ability to make it so widgets will take events, but not take the focus, that would be great.

I already know about the virtual event `<<NotebookTabChanged>>`. However, I'm talking about when you click on an already selected tab. So, the tab isn't changing. I tried just binding the `<Button-1>` event to the Notebook widget, but it didn't do anything.

Since making Notebooks isn't common knowledge to everyone who uses Tkinter, here's an example of how to make a minimal Notebook with tabs. I don't know why the text is cut off in the final tab here, though (but it's not in my full code):

```
from tkinter import *;
from tkinter.ttk import *; #Notebook comes from this

class Editor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk=Tk();
        self.tabs=0;
        self.frame=Frame(self.tk);
        self.nb=Notebook(self.frame);
        self.frame.pack();        
        for x in range(5):
            self.add_tab();
        self.nb.pack();
        self.tk.mainloop();
    def add_tab(self):
        newTabFrame=Frame(self.nb);
        text=Text(newTabFrame); #Just a sample Text widget to go in each tab
        text.pack();
        if self.tabs==0:
            self.nb.add(newTabFrame, text=str(self.tabs), compound=TOP);
        else:
            self.nb.add(newTabFrame, text=str(self.tabs));
        self.tabs+=1;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e=Editor();
    try:
        e.tk.destroy();
    except:
        pass;
```

Comment: 1. Can you show code that creates a notebook? 2. Try binding it directly to the widget you click.

Comment: I added a Python 3 example. I don't see a way offhand to get the tab widgets to bind to them. I'm not even sure if they are widgets, per se, as it takes a completely different process to change the colors and stuff.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I think I was just using bind_all instead of bind. However, if you happen to figure out how to access a tab widget, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, obviously I was doing something wrong, because when I tested out what I *thought* I already tested out on my larger code on the example code I used in my question, it actually worked. Then, I discovered that this works on my larger code, too. Huh. I think I must have been using bind_all instead of bind (whereas I thought I had attempted both), because that really doesn't work. EDIT: Actually, I was attempting to use it without `return "break"` and while that partially works, it doesn't work after you click on a new tab when you directly click on it again. Plus, setting the focus in my answer here with `return "break"` won't solve the problem (although it does answer my question), because it will set the focus on the current tab before it switches tabs. I'll figure something out, I'm sure. EDIT: Changing `Button-1` to `ButtonRelease-1` (or some such) fixes the problem. The `Motion` binding with the same handler, has potential, too, but if you have Toplevel windows popping up, this will take the focus from them if you move the mouse pointer over your tab.

Here's the working code:

```
from tkinter import *;
from tkinter.ttk import *; #Notebook comes from this
from tkinter.messagebox import *;

class Editor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk=Tk();
        self.tabs=0;
        self.frame=Frame(self.tk);
        self.nb=Notebook(self.frame);
        self.nb.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.test);
        self.frame.pack();        
        for x in range(5):
            self.add_tab();
        self.nb.pack();
        self.tk.mainloop();
    def add_tab(self):
        newTabFrame=Frame(self.nb);
        text=Text(newTabFrame);
        text.pack();
        if self.tabs==0:
            self.nb.add(newTabFrame, text=str(self.tabs), compound=TOP);
        else:
            self.nb.add(newTabFrame, text=str(self.tabs));
        self.tabs+=1;
    def test(self, event=None):
        showinfo("Success", "It works!");
        #Imagine the code for selecting the text widget is here.
        return "break";

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e=Editor();
    try:
        e.tk.destroy();
    except:
        pass;
```